# When is an argument without premises valid?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

So the question is how do we know if an argument without premises is valid.

First of all, how would that go? I mean, what would an argument without premises look like (in terms of propositional logic)? Would there just be a conclusion? I also read that in case of a tautology, that would be a valid argument and I simply don't understand how there even can be a truth table created if there are no premises.

Also, why is $p$ or not $p$ an argument without premises? Isn't $p$ itself a premise?

Excuse my probably very simple questions, I'm very new to propositional logic or rather discrete math as a whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I simply don't understand how there even can be a truth table created if there are no premises.

With $n$ statements, there are $2^n$ ways to conjoin each statement or its negation with the others, and $2^{2^n}$ to disjoin these i.e. $2^{2^n}$ truth functions. With no premises, set $n=0$ so there are $2$ truth functions, true and false (or if you prefer, tautology and contradiction). The argument will just be a conclusion, and is valid iff the conclusion is tautological.

> Also, why is $p$ or not $p$ an argument without premises? Isn't $p$ itself a premise?

To assume $p$ would in general be a premise, but that's not what you're doing. The simplest explanation is a comment by Ludwig Wittgenstein: "For example, I know nothing about the weather when I know that it is either raining or not raining."

Answer (score 2):

An *argument* without premises is a single sentence : the conclusion.

A sentence is [valid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validity_(logic)#Valid_formula)

> if and only if it is true under every possible interpretation of the language. In propositional logic, they are [tautologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)).

---

Regarding [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)#Verifying_tautologies), there is no issue with a truth table for a single formula.

Tautologies are exactly those formulas whose rightmost column in the truth table shows only the value TRUE.